# What exactly is the gold covetous serpent ring?

Tags: dark-souls

I have the gold covetous serpent ring does it do anything else other then item discovery increase?

Comment: Is it dark souls 1 or 2?

Comment: Dark Souls 1. Sorry I wasn't specific.

Comment: Nah, you were, I just misread the tag!

Answer (score 5):

No, the ring simply increases drop rates.

In Dark Souls 1 it boosts the wearer's discoverability by 200 and is found in Sen's Fortress

[Source](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/covetous-gold-serpent-ring)

The ring also makes an appearance in Dark Souls 2 again boosting discoverability, but this time by a percentage. You can also find upgraded versions - but they are separate rings (rings cannot be upgraded in DkS2, like equipment).

- Basic ring - 50%
- Ring + 1 - 75%
- Ring + 2 - 100%

Note, it doesn't improve the quality of drops, simply that an item is *more likely* to drop.

[Source](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Covetous+Gold+Serpent+Ring)

Comment: Note: the +1 and +2 variants are only available in Dark Souls 2. Not the original.

Comment: The ring has a different effect in Dark Souls 1. It doesn't increase by a percentage, but increases the item discovery value by 200. And there are no + variants as Ben mentioned.

Comment: Balls. Evidently misread the tag haha!